# CSS: Translate background-position percentage to pixels?

Tags: jquery, css

I'll keep this short and sweet.

I've a class with `background-position: center`, which is 100% width and height of the window. I'm been attempting to animate this background position by adding and subtracting pixels to it in jQuery, however ..

```
$('.playground').css('background-position-x')
```

&&

```
$('.playground').css('background-position-y')
```

.. both return `50%` as the class is centered, understandably.

I was wondering if it would be at all possible for me to convert this value to pixels?